# Android APK installs multiple icons / activities?

Tags: android, layout, android-activity, installation, apk

I have one program that has multiple layouts/activities. I install the APK and i have 3 APP icons in my installed apps location! I thought it was maybe my debugging environment, but now I know it's caused by the APK package. The icons seem to have the names of some of the activities/layouts I have within the program. I only want one launch point, one application to show. It really screws things up, because if I click the wrong icon, it crashes the program.

Is there some sort of parameter to set to prevent an activity from becoming a launch point, or is it something completely different?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shall edit your manifest file and remove `intent-filter` entry from all activities you do not want to be shown by launcher. So keep this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

only for that one you want to be your entry point.