# Android APK installs multiple icons?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk

I guys I need some help.
I made a app, but when I install, the program install other 3 Icons.
Can you help me solving my problem ? 
I have seen this [Android APK installs multiple icons / activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937578/android-apk-installs-multiple-icons-activities) but I don't know where is the "intent-filter" . 
Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Intent filter tags are defined in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file of your app (and of libraries that you include in your project).

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest.xml make sure only your chosen launch activity has the MAIN/LAUNCHER intent filter. I suspect you're creating Activities using the Android Studio wizard and checking the launcher checkbox each time.